# Setting some 2d array labels to zero in python

Tags: python, numpy, label

My goal is to set some labels in 2d array to zero without using a for loop. Is there a faster numpy way to do this without the for loop? The ideal scenario would be `temp_arr[labeled_im not in labels] = 0`, but it's not really working the way I'd like it to.

```
labeled_array = np.array([[1,2,3],
                          [4,5,6],
                          [7,8,9]])

labels = [2,4,5,6,8]
temp_arr = np.zeros((labeled_array.shape)).astype(int)
for label in labels:
    temp_arr[labeled_array == label] = label

>> temp_arr
[[0 2 0]
 [4 5 6]
 [0 8 0]]
```

The for loop gets quite slow when there are a lot of iterations to go through, so it is important to improve the execution time with numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use define `labels` as a set and use `temp_arr = np.where(np.isin(labeled_array, labels), labeled_array, 0)`. Although, the difference for such a small array does not seem to be significant.

```
import numpy as np
import time

labeled_array = np.array([[1,2,3],
                          [4,5,6],
                          [7,8,9]])

labels = [2,4,5,6,8]

start = time.time()
temp_arr_0 = np.zeros((labeled_array.shape)).astype(int)
for label in labels:
    temp_arr_0[labeled_array == label] = label
end = time.time()

print(f"Loop takes {end - start}")

start = time.time()
temp_arr_1 = np.where(np.isin(labeled_array, labels), labeled_array, 0)
end = time.time()

print(f"np.where takes {end - start}")

labels  = {2,4,5,6,8}

start = time.time()
temp_arr_2 = np.where(np.isin(labeled_array, labels), labeled_array, 0)
end = time.time()

print(f"np.where with set takes {end - start}")
```

outputs

```
Loop takes 5.3882598876953125e-05
np.where takes 0.00010514259338378906
np.where with set takes 3.314018249511719e-05
```

Comment: Using for loop for the dataset which I had, the code executed for 34 seconds. Using your provided method it only took 0.4 seconds, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the case the labels are unique in `labels` (and memory isn't a concern), here's a way to go.

As the very first step, we convert labels to a `ndarray`

```
labels = np.array(labels)
```

Then, we produce two broadcastable arrays from `labeled_array` and `labels`

```
labeled_row = labeled_array.ravel()[np.newaxis, :]
labels_col = labels[:, np.newaxis]
```

The above code block produces respectively a row array of shape (1,9)

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

and a column array of shape (5,1)

```
array([[2],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [8]])
```

Now the two shapes are broadcastable (see [this page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)), so we can perform elementwise comparison, e.g.

```
mask = labeled_row == labels_col
```

which returns a (5,9)-shaped boolean mask

```
array([[False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False]])
```

In the case the assumption above is fullfilled, you'll have a number of `True` values per row equal to the number of times the corresponding label appears in your `labeled_array`. Nonetheless, you can also have all-`False` rows, e.g. when a label in `labels` never appears in your `labeled_array`.

To find out which labels actually appeared in your `labeled_array`, you can use `np.nonzero` on the boolean mask

```
indices = np.nonzero(mask)
```

which returns a tuple containing the row and column indices of the non-zero (i.e. `True`) elements

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64), array([1, 3, 4, 5, 7], dtype=int64))
```

By construction, the first element of the tuple above tells you which labels actually appeared in your `labeled_array`, e.g.

```
appeared_labels = labels[indices[0]]
```

(note that you can have consecutive elements in `appeared_labels` if that specific label appeared more than once in your `labeled_array`).

We can now build and fill the output array:

```
out = np.zeros(labeled_array.size, dtype=int)
out[indices[1]] = labels[indices[0]]
```

and bring it back to the original shape

```
out = out.reshape(*labeled_array.shape)
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 8, 0]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for my particular case @Dilara's answered worked well.